# What Is the full list of hormonal changes pre period?

Tags: menstrual-cycle

I am having surprising difficulty finding a complete scientific description of the hormonal changes that occur in a premenopausal woman in the days before her period.

Is there a good resource for this information?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstruation#/media/File:Figure_28_02_07.jpg How about this?

Comment: It might help to edit your post and describe what you know already and what is missing in your opinion - what makes you think, the descriptions you've found already were incomplete. This will help us to answer your actual question.

Answer (score 3):

After a “LH-Surge” (LH - Lutheinizing Hormone) (which occurs around day 12 of cycle due to inverting the effect of estradiol on the secretion of LH from the adenohypohysis) the ovulation occurs and the second phase of menstrual cycle, the luteal phase, begins. The remaining parts of the dominant follicle are transformed into the corpus luteum, which produces progesterone and oestrogen (these are probably what you’re looking for). Because progesterone sends negative feedback to hypothalamus, levels of FSH (Follicle-stimulating Hormone; important in the first phase of the cycle) and LH fall. As a result, corpus luteum atrophies and menstruation begins. In case of fertilisation of the egg however, hCG (human chorionic gonadotropin) is produced (by blastocyst, later syncytiotrophoblast) which preserves corpus luteum and therefore maintains levels of progesterone and oestrogen.

P.S. If you take a look at the follicular phase, you'll also find a couple of additional regulatory hormones, such as inhibins, activins or local secretion of prostaglangines etc.

Sources:
Rassow, J. (2016). *Biochemie.* Stuttgart : Thieme.
Pape, H.-C.; Kurtz, A.; Silbernagl, S. (2018). *Physiologie.* Stuttgart; New York : Georg Thieme Verlag.
(both books in German and below is a brief Wikipedia article)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menstrual_cycle